# Chrome can't detect capture device when running audiocapture code

Tags: google-chrome, audio, sdl, audio-recording, emscripten

I'm tring to run audio record and playback feature in a browser.

I use the [sample code of SDL2](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/blob/master/test/testaudioinfo.c), 
and also use emcc to compile it to `.html`.

When I run the html in chrome, it can't detect the audio capture device.

I've tested it in windows and ubuntu, both the same.

However, using Microsoft Edge and Firefox, the capture device is able to be detected.

Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: Sounds like it's a good time to ask it directly in Emscripten issue. They are fast to respond so try it.

Comment: I posted a question in github and got the anwser: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/9318